# Cannot assign string array to an asp:HiddenField

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I’m trying to assign the array (globalaProviders) content to an asp hidden field (aProvidersHdn) and obtain the values in the server once a WebLinkButton (custom control) has been clicked.

In the Javascript code below, I’m able to assign the string values from a JSON file to the globalaProviders array. When I try to assign the values in the array to the hidden field (aProvidersHdn)I obtain an empty value in the client and therefore the server.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">function bbPlusPullTest()
{
globalaProviders=[];
aProvidersHdn="";
$.each(providers, function(i,v){

globalaProviders[i,0]=v.uri;
     globalaProviders[i,1]=v.name;
     globalaProviders[i,2]=v.description;
});

$("#<%=aProvidersHdn.ClientID%>").val(globalaProviders);
alert("aProvidersHdn = "+ aProvidersHdn); 
//empty value obtained
}
</script>

//I’ve added this to trigger a postback after the WebLinkButton(custom control) is clicked so the values of the hidden field can be send to the server.
<% if (!Page.IsPostBack) { %>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
   __doPostBack("<%= MedicalHistory.ClientID %>", "");
}
</script>
```

Here is the assignment of the hidden field: ASPX

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="aProvidersHdn" runat="server" /> 

//Custom Control Does not has a Click event
<cc1:WebLinkButtonControl ID="MedicalHistory" Key="viewccd" PostBackUrl="BBPlusPullTest.aspx" CssClass="panelitem" runat="server"></cc1:WebLinkButtonControl>
```

Here is the code in the SERVER

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
MedicalHistory.Attributes.Add("onclick", "bbPlusPullTest(); return false;");
}
else
{
string providersArray = aProviders.Value;
}
```

Here is the code for providers:

```
providers = function(registries, callback){

    var requests = [];
    jQuery.each(registries, function(i, r){
      requests.push(jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: r+"prov.json"
      }));
    });

    var providers = [];
    jQuery.when.apply(null, requests).then(function(){
      jQuery.each(arguments, function(responseNum, arg){
        if (responseNum>=requests.length) {
          return;
        }
        jQuery.each(arg, function(i, provider){
          providers.push(provider);
        });
      });
      callback(providers);
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just join strings from your array with some delimiter
And then split result string by this delimiter on server side

Comment: I tried joining the strings in the array using delimiters, but still have the same problem.  My problem is that I’m getting empty values in the hiddenfield (aProvidersHdn) at the client and the server.  Apparently, the content in the array isn’t passed to the hiddenfield in the following code: 
    $("#<%=aProvidersHdn.ClientID%>").val(globalaProviders);

Comment: oops, you have array of arrays, not just array of strings. in this case you'd better write some js function for converting this array to string and then on the server side another method for making opposite conversion.

Comment: I have is a two dimensional array of strings and what I’m trying to do is to assign the content of the two dimensional array of strings into the asp:hiddenField.  In the code above I test with an alert the hidden field and it results in an empty string.  I’ve also tested writing the values directly from the JSON file to the hidden field using (“|||”) as delimiters, and still get an empty value in the hidden field (this is not included in the code above).

Comment: May you show me code there you fill the "providers" JS variable (first argument of your $.each call)

Comment: Do you think this call is the correct one to assign the content of the array (globalaProviders) to the asp hidden field (aProvidersHdn) and is the call in the right place in the code?: $("#<%=aProvidersHdn.ClientID%>").val(globalaProviders);

Comment: I don't know, but according to your code you fill globalaProviders array from providers (I guess, array of objects). And main question is does this providers array has values when function bbPlusPullTest calls?

Comment: Yes, providers has values when function bbPlusPullTest executes. I just added the code for providers in the initial question.

Comment: Providers is a function, but you pass it as an object. So $.each can't iterate through it, because this is he function object, not array object.